# Replace a string in a line using shell script

Tags: shell

File name : URL.java

Content:

```
public static String serverURL = "http://100.140.0.60:8080";
public static String serverURL1 = "http://100.140.0.60:8080";
public static String serverURL2 = "http://100.140.0.60:8080";
public static String serverURL3 = "http://100.140.0.60:8080";
```

In the above file ,

I need to change the ServerURL variable value to http://80.140.0.80:8080 dynamically using shell script

Note:

Should not change the value dynamically based on line number.

Some extra lines will get added to this file on future.
So i need to change the serverURL variable value based on some condition .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` for this, like so:

```
sed -i "s/STRING_TO_REPLACE/STRING_TO_REPLACE_WITH/g" <file>
```

Though you need to take care to escape the slashes and dots, so in your case

```
sed -i "s/http:\/\/100\.140\.0\.60:8080/http:\/\/80.140.0.80:8080\//g" URL.java
```

You can put this in a shell script, if I understood your "dynamically" correct.

If you want more flexibility, then you should look into `awk` or `perl` scripting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a similar approach to change only the IP in the line containing the port `8080`. For example to invoke the change you show above, you need only:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\}[.][0-9]\{1,3\}\(:8080\)/80.140.0.80\1/'
```

Which would result in the IP for the address with port `8080` being:

```
public static String serverURL = http://80.140.0.80:8080
```